# Show Chm file using Help.ShowHelp()

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to show local chm file in new window without disturbing background using **help.showhelp(control, path)** on-click in web-browser on server side. I was passing control object without any parameters and it was displaying the chm file with clearing of the div contents. How to overcome this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Might show some screenshot of the actual problem? Also remember that CHM files are considered unsafe when not on a trusted storage (i.e. on a shared network drive or the Internet) and won't be displayed.

Comment: @Mario Thanks for taking intrest to help me. I have resolved the issue, actually the problem is with page loading. Since i was using Ispostback to load stuff, it is skipping the condition and making the div null. However at the end found whats going wrong and fixed it.

Comment: If the actual problem isn't too specific (i.e.: might happen to others), you could write an answer of your own and mark it as the solution later on.

Comment: @Mario I have answered to this question. Can you let me know if any extra information to be added to it.

Comment: While I'm not 100% sure about the initial problem, this sounds fine to me. Mark it as an answer/solution, if others object, they can still create their own answer or comment yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Server Side Scripting**

Since I was making a server call onclick of help link the Page_Load method in the **aspx.cs** file is called and tries to assign the values to the fields. Here I have a condition where if it **IsPostback** to skip the set of statements. So the those fields are made null. To avoid that I have declared the fields out of the **IsPostback** condition.

**Client Side**
To avoid the complete page to reload I was using update panel.

```
 < asp:ScriptManager ID="smAJAX1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release" >< /asp:ScriptManager >
    < asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
        < ContentTemplate >
            < a href="#" runat="server" class="" title="Help File" onserverclick="helpdoc">help</a >                
        < /ContentTemplate >
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```